# selenium-webdriver with Safari - Error: Server terminated early with status 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to launch `safari` using `selenium-webdriver` on a MAC server, but I'm getting the following error

```
Error: Server terminated early with status 1
    at earlyTermination.catch.e (/Users/administrator/repos/myproj/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:251:52)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

Output from safari driver on the server:

```
administrator$ /usr/bin/safaridriver
Could not start server: must specify at least one configuration argument.

Usage: safaridriver [options]
        -h, --help                Prints out this usage information.
        -p, --port                Port number the driver should use. If the server
                                  is already running, the port cannot be changed.
                                  If port 0 is specified, a default port will be used.
        --enable                  Applies configuration changes so that subsequent WebDriver
                                  sessions will run without further authentication.
```

**Note: on the server if I specify a port it does nothing, on my local machine it listen to requests**

Code used to start safari

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
// ...

const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('safari').build();
```

**On my local machine I don't get any errors.**

Both my machine and the server are using the same Safari version.

Is there anything that I have to install on the server that I might have on my machine but not in the server?

Why is it not working in the remote server?

Answer (score -1):

So, I ran this command

```
# To disable Screen Sharing 
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist 
# To enable Screen Sharing 
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist
```

And connected to the machine through Safari `vnc://<ip>`

With the interface mode I executed the command without any errors. So it seems it will not work properly running from SSH